# SIP/2.0 400 Sip message body is shorter that is indicated by the content length

Tags: networking, sip

During SIP communicating between my application, Freeswitch, and nextiva trunk, I am getting the following error message from `208.73.146.95`:

```
 SIP/2.0 400 Sip message body is shorter that is indicated by the content length
```

The previous message is one INCOMING to FS ans is

```
 SIP/2.0 100 Trying
```

And before previous message is

```
INVITE sip:MYNUMBER@208.73.146.95 SIP/2.0
```

which content length is exactly correct. Many more previous messages are without contents, and long before message is again has exact length.

What this message can mean?

Comment: Are you sending over UDP or TCP? If over UDP, the Content-Length header must match the datagram packet size (minus initial line + headers. Just a guess.

Comment: It sending over `UDP`. I counted characters of "data" part in plain text editor and the number coincided with the value.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a Bad request message for larger Content Length than the body of a SIP message. If you send it over UDP the receiving party will respond with 400 Bad Request error, if you send it over TCP, receiving party will wait for more data for a certain period of time. Let's have an example:

```
INVITE sip:user@example.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP host5.example.com;branch=z9hG4bK-39234-23523
Max-Forwards: 80
To: sip:j.user@example.com
From: sip:caller@example.net;tag=93942939o2
Contact: <sip:caller@hungry.example.net>
Call-ID: clerr.0ha0isndaksdjweiafasdk3
CSeq: 11 INVITE
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 10000

v=0
o=mhandley 29739 7272939 IN IP4 208.73.146.95
c=IN IP4 208.73.146.95
t=0 0
m=audio 49217 RTP/AVP 0 12
m=video 3227 RTP/AVP 31
a=rtpmap:31 LPC
```

Here is an example of SIP message for which receiving party will respond with such Bad request. Because "Contnt-Length: 10000" is not a valid header information in this SIP message. To calculate actual Content-Length, you should count characters of the body part of this message. Here body part is starting from "v=0.......a=rtpmap:31 LPC". You can easily count the characters of this body part using a online character counting tool such as http://www.charactercountonline.com/ .
So, actual header information should be with **"Content-Length: 145"** for this sip message. The reference of this information is https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4475 .
Hope this answer will be helpful to someone.